# sharing constant between models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to have constat defined in two models, but I don't want to repeat code. I've placed this constant in `config/application.rb`. Is that a good practice? Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Why do you want the constant to be defined in multiple places? Is there a reason you don't want to define the constant in one class and reference that class + constant from your other class(es)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better place to declare application constants would be in a .rb file in config/initializers folder.
Declaring a constant in an initializer (or as you have done in config/application.rb) makes it available in ALL models/controllers/views in your application.